# What does it mean when my Pokemon has a exclamation mark over them during battle?

Tags: pokemon-quest

Sometimes when I'm in battle, an exclamation mark appears over my the Pokemon in my team:

[image]

I see it most frequently during the final boss fight of level 10-5, against the three Dodrios.

What does this marker indicate?

Comment: I think it might be the taunt indicator but I'm not 100% sure